# fib6_rule_lookup invocation

Tags: kernel

I have a network module which encapsulate a packet if it's destination is not local or a direct connected network. To do that, I have a function that detects if this packet is local or not. This function is for IPv4 packets and I should duplicate it to do the same for IPv6. 
The code of the function for IPv4 is:

```
bool is_v4addr_local(struct iphdr *iph, const struct net_device *output_dev)
{
    struct flowi fl;
    struct rtable *rt;
    struct net_device *dev;

    if(output_dev == NULL) {
          printk(KERN_DEBUG "output_dev is NULL!");
          return 0;
    }
    memset(&fl, 0, sizeof(fl));
    fl.u.ip4.daddr = iph->daddr;
    fl.flowi_tos = RTO_ONLINK; //locally connected
    rt = ip_route_output_key(dev_net(output_dev), &fl.u.ip4);
    if (IS_ERR(rt))
        return 0;
    dev = rt->dst.dev;
    ip_rt_put(rt);
    if (!dev)
        return 0;

    // If we got anything, it's local
    return 1;
}
```

To adapt it I think I should use the function fib6_rule_lookup but I done know how to introduce the last parameter of the function (in some examples they only put ip6_pol_route_lookup but it doesn't work).

Could you help me to adapt this function? Is the first time I program in kernel space.

Thanks

```
bool is_v6addr_local(struct ipv6hdr *iph, const struct net_device *output_dev)
{
    struct rt6_info *rt;
    struct net_device *dev;
    struct dst_entry *dst;
    struct flowi6 fl6;


    if(output_dev == NULL) {
          printk(KERN_DEBUG "output_dev is NULL!");
          return 0;
    }

    memset(&fl6, 0, sizeof(fl6));
    fl6.flowi6_tos = RTO_ONLINK;
    fl6.daddr = iph->daddr;


    dst = fib6_rule_lookup(dev_net(output_dev), &fl6, 0, ip6_pol_route_lookup);
    if (dst->error != 0)
        return 0;
    rt = (struct rt6_info *) dst;

    dev = rt->dst.dev;
    if (!dev)
        return 0;

    // If we got anything, it's local*/
    return 1;
}
```